# MySQL - Looking for Top 10 records by Month

Tags: mysql, group-by, union

I will preface with Table Structures:

revshare r : contains info for a purchase including orderNo, sales, commission, itemid, EventDate

Products p: contains information around a product including a PID (Product ID) and is used to join to the Merchants table to get Merchant information.

Merchants m: contains information about the merchant the product was purchased from, including MerchantName

**Question**

I am trying to create a MySQL query to pull top 10 itemid's ordered by sum of commission for a given month.  The entire data set I would like to get is from 2011-2013 so each year would populate 120 records (10 per month).

I created a query to pull 1 months worth of data and planned on using a UNION ALL to just create a records list with 10 records from each query (each individual query representing a months top 10 itemid's).

**Query1**

This query accurately returns me the top 10 itemid's based on total commission of those items in the given month period.

```
SELECT 
m.MerchantName, 
Count(r.OrderNo), 
sum(r.commission)

FROM revshare r
LEFT JOIN Products p ON r.itemid = p.PID
LEFT JOIN Merchants m ON p.MID = m.MID

WHERE r.EventDate between '2011-01-01' and '2011-01-31'

GROUP by r.itemid
ORDER by 3 DESC LIMIT 10
```

When I try to UNION this query with another so that I can get records for the next month between '2011-02-01' and '2011-02-31' I get and error "ERROR: Incorrect usage of UNION and ORDER BY"  I know this is because apparently you cannot use ORDER BY on any set of UNION'd queries but the last.  I could pull the entire data set and then use Excel or Pentaho BI to show only the top 10 but that is not efficient based on the huge data sets in the revshare table.

Below is the query with the UNION ALL that doesn't work.  Does anyone have any better method of pulling this data?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Regards,
-Chris

**Query 2 (doesn't work because of the ORDER BY statement)**

```
SELECT 
m.MerchantName, 
Count(r.OrderNo), 
sum(r.commission)

FROM revshare r
LEFT JOIN Products p ON r.itemid = p.PID
LEFT JOIN Merchants m ON p.MID = m.MID

WHERE r.EventDate between '2011-01-01' and '2011-01-31'

GROUP by r.itemid
ORDER by 3 DESC LIMIT 10

UNION ALL

SELECT 
m.MerchantName, 
Count(r.OrderNo), 
sum(r.commission)

FROM revshare r
LEFT JOIN Products p ON r.itemid = p.PID
LEFT JOIN Merchants m ON p.MID = m.MID

WHERE r.EventDate between '2011-02-01' and '2011-02-31'

GROUP by r.itemid
ORDER by 3 DESC LIMIT 10
```

Comment: You're calling "order by 3." The order by directive is looking for a column name.

Comment: No the order by directive uses the column position or column name, that's not the issue.  The issue is the order by directive in a UNION situation. So I could say "ORDER BY 3" or "ORDER BY r.commission" and it means the same thing.

Comment: Learn something new everyday.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, try this....

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT 
    m.MerchantName, 
    Count(r.OrderNo), 
    sum(r.commission)
  FROM
    revshare r
    LEFT JOIN Products p ON r.itemid = p.PID
    LEFT JOIN Merchants m ON p.MID = m.MID
  WHERE
    r.EventDate between '2011-01-01' and '2011-01-31'
  GROUP by
    r.itemid
  ORDER by 
    3 DESC LIMIT 10
) AS RESULT1

UNION ALL

SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT 
    m.MerchantName, 
    Count(r.OrderNo), 
    sum(r.commission)
  FROM
    revshare r
    LEFT JOIN Products p ON r.itemid = p.PID
    LEFT JOIN Merchants m ON p.MID = m.MID
  WHERE
    r.EventDate between '2011-02-01' and '2011-02-31'
  GROUP by
    r.itemid
  ORDER by
    3 DESC LIMIT 10
) AS RESULT2
```

Comment: Worked out perfectly, Thanks Chuck, I see now that I need to subquery the unions. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Since you already started down the path of `union`ing queries together, here is the right approach:

```
select t.*
from ((SELECT '2011-01' as yyyymm, m.MerchantName, Count(r.OrderNo) as cnt, sum(r.commission) as comm
       FROM revshare r LEFT JOIN
            Products p
            ON r.itemid = p.PID LEFT JOIN
            Merchants m
            ON p.MID = m.MID
       WHERE r.EventDate between '2011-01-01' and '2011-01-31'
       GROUP by r.itemid
       ORDER by comm DESC
       LIMIT 10
      ) union all
      (SELECT '2011-02' as yyyymm, m.MerchantName, Count(r.OrderNo) as cnt, sum(r.commission) as comm
       FROM revshare r LEFT JOIN
            Products p
            ON r.itemid = p.PID LEFT JOIN
            Merchants m
            ON p.MID = m.MID
       WHERE r.EventDate between '2011-02-01' and '2011-02-28'
       GROUP by r.itemid
       ORDER by comm DESC LIMIT 10
      ) union all
      . . .
     ) t
order by 1, comm desc
```

In other words, you need to use subqueries for the `union all`.  Note that I also added in `yyyymm` to identify the month.

Comment: This works as well, thanks very much Gordon, and thank you twice for your explanation of me having to use subqueries.  Appreciate it.